# Selenium Webdriver - Cannot click button - Finds element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hopefully someone can help me with a solution to my problem. I have spent the better part of the day trying nearly every solution I can find on here and through Google.

I will cut to the chase. I have a test that logs in on one screen. The second screen selects a role and moves on. I am able to get to the role selection screen, but cannot move forward as Selenium will not click the button, regardless of what I do.

The interesting thing is that this will work with the IDE, but exporting the code to java and running it with the webdriver does not work either. This part makes no sense to me as I would think the IDE export should run easily. The only difference I can see is that the webdriver pulls up a profile-less Firefox, whereas the IDE is running on my profile - not sure that this would have anything to do with it, but wanted to throw that out there.

The only difference between the first button and the second button is the autofocus command in the HTML.

```
<button data-submit-button="" class="btn" autofocus="" name="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
```

I've tried numerous solutions found throughout the web and the last thing I've tried is

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.name("submit")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
```

This does not work either. I have tried several variations on this and most of the time the webdriver either times out or skips through this step, passing it and then failing on the next steps as the page has not moved forward.

Does anyone have any suggestions? If you have any questions or I can give you more information if I haven't given enough! Any help with this would be amazing, as I've spent the better part of the day trying to get through this one issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the selector is the main issue in the scenario like this. Also, `name="submit"` is not even a very safe selector to use since developers have tendency to duplicate the same attribute across the form. Without knowing about the actual elements I can pretty much tell you the issue is the selector. If the text **Go** is the only text of the button on that page, give the following xpath a shot

```
//button[@name='submit'][@type='submit'][contains(text(),'Go')]
```

Complete implementation should look like as follows:

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//button[@name='submit'][@type='submit'][contains(text(),'Go')]");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));

myDynamicElement.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, it's still giving me issues. I am getting the following when running...

    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //button[@name='submit'][@type='submit'][containts(text(),'Go')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[@name='submit'][@type='submit'][containts(text(),'Go')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: I am sorry there was a typo in `contains()`. Corrected, please try again

Comment: plus one  - I've followed a few of your answers and you succinctly always manage to hit the nail on the head - nice one.

Comment: @jimtollan Appreciate it. I try to share my knowledge after all that's a great way of learning as well